# Building an embedded system

Tags: microcontroller, usb, wifi

I want to build an embedded system with USB and Wifi. I am going to use USB to load configuration and code. Wifi will be used to communicate with other similar systems. I would also like to program at the socket level, which means I want the drivers for USB and Wifi already available and an OS. So if someone can point me to a set of things I might need to bootstrap such a system, it would be very helpful. Or an existing system with an RTOS that can be used would be great too.

Comment: Question is overly broad...

Comment: Broad pointers would help, like choices of chips...

Comment: There are 1000's of choices which is why the question is too broad. Take a look at a Raspberry Pi (which can take a USB WiFi Dongle) for example and let us know if there's anything that couldn't do you need.

Comment: Here's a broad answer in the spirit of broadness of the question: Use a single-board-computer :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a single-board computer (SBC), such as the many ARM-based boards out there now.

To simplify the WiFi part, look for an SBC with integrated WiFi. The alternative is WiFi modules and drivers / code, plus compatibility fiddling-around, for the SBC chosen.

For a reasonably standardized operating platform, opt for one of the several Linux-based SBCs.

Some SBC options:

- The Olimex [A13-OLinuXino-WIFI](https://www.olimex.com/Products/OLinuXino/A13/A13-OLinuXino-WIFI/) is brilliantly priced for its features, runs Linux
- The [BeagleBoard xM](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9978) has its own fan following, and excellent open source module ecosystem
- The [Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/) is definitely the most hyped, best marketed product in this space - the iAnything of the SBC space. Whether that makes it the best would depend on the fanboy-credentials of the person you ask.

Comment: Voted up for calling out the over-hyped Pi.

Comment: That Olimex board has a good feature set for the price, I'll keep that in mind for future projects but won't throw out my beloved Pi just yet :P